# react-router routes with /yourRoute not /#/aRoute

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, url-routing

I am new to react-router and wondering if I can get some help on some basic stuff I have on my project.  I have the router running, and all works well except when I go to my route `/about` (my only route) I get "Cannot GET /about" but when I go to `/#/about` it goes to the route successfully.  Using Link works as well but uses the `/#/about` route.  In summary my project looks like:

```
render((
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Layout}>
      <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>
  ),
```

document.getElementById('app'))

and

```
export default class Layout extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
          <Link to="/" class="navbar-brand">React Router Test</Link>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div id="page">
    {this.props.children}
    </div>
    <footer class="footer">
      <div class="container">
        <p class="text-muted">Place sticky footer content here.</p>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </div>
);
  }
}
```

and about component

```
const styles = {}
styles.body = {
  margin: 70,
}
export default React.createClass({
  render() {
    return <div style={styles.body}>About</div>
  }
})
```

Please let me know how I can get the app to recognize `/about` and not just `/#/about`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version of `react-router` how to exactly access and change this might differ but the gist should be the same.

You're currently using a hash history. This means your url's will be built using a hash. An other option is the use the browser history. This enables the clean urls `www.example.com/about`.

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'
render((
  <Router history={browserHistory }>
    <Route path="/" component={Layout}>
      <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>
  ),
```

https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md

Ps. If above doesn't work please consult the docs for react-router and the version you are using. They've had some API changes and package changes in this department (the [history](https://github.com/reactjs/history) package is effectively powering this behavior).

Comment: hmm didn't work. Do i need to npm install history and link it in somewhere?

Comment: Depending on your version of react-router, yes you should. Here is the link for v1.x. https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/1.0.x/docs/guides/basics/Histories.md

Comment: hmmm, i got it to use browserHistory and the link doesn't use #, but for some reason I still get the get error when trying to reference a route in the url...

Comment: Have you configured your server to return the page with the react app on that url? Otherwise it won't know to actually return that the base html page and react-router won't be able to be initialized.